# reading from a txt file to a 2D matrix in C++

Tags: c++, matrix, ifstream

I m trying to read from a txt file which is ;

```
0 1 1 1 0 0 0 
1 0 0 0 1 0 0 
1 0 0 0 1 1 0 
1 0 0 0 0 1 0 
0 1 1 0 0 1 0 
0 0 1 1 1 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

and copy it into a 2D matrix. Following code tries to do it

```
int readFile(int indirectedAdjacencyList[][7])
{
       ifstream dPathList;
       dPathList.open ("input.txt");

       for(int i=0; i<7; i++)
       {
        for (int j=0; j<7; j++)
        {
            dPathList >> indirectedAdjacencyList[i][j];
            }

       }

    dPathList.close();
    return 0;
}
```

but it seems there is a problem in my code. in 2D matrix I have only zeros but the size of matrix is ok (7x7) .is there anyone could tell me what is wrong with it ?

Comment: What's the problem? What's not working in the way you would expect?

Comment: in 2D matrix I have only zeros but the size of matrix is ok (7x7)

Comment: Are you sure the file is even open?  Check `dPathList.good()`

Comment: @JoeZ Or even `dPathList.is_open()`

Comment: I have no idea about how can I do it :)

Comment: `dPathList.open("input.txt"); if (!dPathList.is_open()) cerr << "oops the file isn't open\n";` **Always** check if files open successfully. There's too many reasons that they might not.

Comment: is " dPathList.open("input.txt")  " not enough ??

Comment: @zaratushtra `open` opens a file, but sometimes it fails, you must check to see if it has failed. The most likely reason for a file failing to open is that it doesn't exist in the place where your program is looking for it. **Always** check to see if your file opens successfully.